# Bookshelf.js get pivot table attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am trying to get attributes from my m-n relational mySql table using Bookshelf.js.

I have a table users: id, name
and tournaments: id, place
and a pivot table: user_id, tournament_id, teamname

Those are my models:

```
var User = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    tournaments: function () {
        return this.belongsToMany(Tournament);
    }
});
var Users = Bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: User
});
var Tournament = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'tournaments',

    users: function () {
        return this.belongsToMany(User);
    }
});
var Tournaments = Bookshelf.Collection.extend({
    model: Tournament
});
var Tournaments_Users = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'tournaments_users'
});
```

Now when I do

```
Tournaments.forge().fetch({withRelated: ['users']})
.then(function (collection) {
    res.send(collection.toJSON());
})
```

I get

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "place": "Berlin",
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Jim",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Tom",
        }, ...
}
```

What I want:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "place": "Berlin",
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Jim",
            "teamname" : "Team A"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Tom",
            "teamname" : "Team B"
        }, ...
}
```

Anyone knows how to do this using Bookshelf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `.withPivot()` method.

Use it like this :

```
users: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany(User).withPivot(['teamname']);
}
```

In your return, you will get a field named `_pivot_teamname`. Just rename them to get it good.
Documentation : http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-withPivot

As long as I know, there is no way to fetch the pivot fields with a custom name.